# Where does Internet Explorer stores its form data history that is uses for auto completion?

Tags: forms, internet-explorer, storage

Where does Internet Explorer stores its form data history that is uses for auto completion?

I need to make a tool the cleans IE form data.

Is there an API for this?
Or what are the registry keys?

Answer (score 5):

Autocomplete data is stored in the registry in two places:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IntelliForms\Storage1
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IntelliForms\Storage2

Direct manipulation is not supported.

Technically, the IE7+ API to do this is:

rundll32.exe inetcpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 48

But I'm not sure this is formally supported for public callers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the registry keys are, but you could work it out by taking a snapshot of your registry, then deleting your form data history, and comparing it and seeing what's different.

I doubt there's an API for it, but that's just a guess.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at "[Clear All History](http://www.clearallhistory.com/download.html)" Its a tool to do what you exactly need.

You will find similar open source tools. Try googling for them.

In Hindsight you would also want to check out [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/). Its freeware and equally a fantastic tool to keep, amongst others, your internet history clean.