# Internet Explorer AutoComplete Form Data

Tags: internet-explorer, computer-forensics

I am looking to load, display and have the user remove stored AutoComplete data from Internet Explorer using c#. I am looking specifically for form data and not stored credentials.

Not sure if IE version matters, but I do believe Windows version makes a difference. 
The settings can be found in Internet Options: under the Content tab by clicking the Settings button in the AutoComplete section.

Answer (score 3):

The autocomplete entries and saved passwords are stored in the registry, specifically:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IntelliForms\Storage1

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1278050/534406) shows exactly where, and [this page](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/windows-forensics-registry-and-file-system-spots#Internet%20Explorer%20Forms%20AutoComplete) confirms it. I've also tested it on IE11 and can confirm that entries get created in this area of the registry when saving passwords and autocomplete. So, using standard Windows API calls or PowerShell can get that information for you, and also delete it (simply by deleting the directories under IntelliForms).

Note that the data is stored in binary or hex, so you would need to reverse-engineer that if you want to present it in a readable format.

Comment: On my windows 8.1, I do not have the Storage1 key. Under IntelliForms, I do have binary values with the name such as "29B0B499F3DBD4B54558A02022DC5D99E95CEADAD7". Not sure if this is the same.

Comment: I think you see the same as what I see. On WIn7 and IE11, under Intelliforms, I get a Storage2 directory created as soon as I save a password, and FormData as soon as it makes an autocomplete entry. The directory structure might just be different on Win8, but I imagine the binary data has the same format (always one entry, and data changes each time new autocomplete values are added).